# How to install qt4 on Jetson Nano with Ubuntu 20.04 for Hector Slam?

Tags: qt4, ubuntu-20.04, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, slam

How to Install qt4 on Jetson Nano (ubuntu 20.04) for Hector Slam

Firstly, I tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
```

this code and tried to install the needed libraries, but in my opinion it couldn't find the libraries again because of the jetson nano's architecture.

Then I tried to download the debian packages from the internet and realized most of them are amd64 packages, I find one package for arm64, but this one needs dependencys as shown below

[tried to install downloaded package for 20.04 and arm64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIgyk.png)

When this gives an error, I tried to download the qt5 then change the version manually, as shown below it doesn't work and says run make install (don't know how to do)

[qt version 4.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL2nE.png)

I can't restart with 18.04 on jetson, so much work done until now.
I need to install qt4 to run Hector Slam. What should I do any suggestions?